# How can I use picture tag in CommonMark (MarkDown)?

Tags: php, html, markdown, jpeg, webp

I use [commonmark](https://commonmark.thephpleague.com) to use `MarkDown` in my PHP project.
I want to use `WEBP` in my project but some browsers not support it, so I want to use `<picture>` tag to use both `WEBP` and `JPG` formats.

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="flower.webp">
  <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="flower.jpg">
  <img src="flower.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

How can I use this in CommonMark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a bit but I made an Extension. I had to figure out how extensions in [league/commonmark](https://github.com/thephpleague/commonmark) work so be patient if some features are missing or if it is not working perfectly.

You can install it with

```
composer require n0sz/commonmark-picture-extension
```

## Usage:

```php
use League\CommonMark\Environment\Environment;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\CommonMark\CommonMarkCoreExtension;
use N0sz\CommonMark\Picture\PictureExtension;

$environment = new Environment();
$environment->addExtension(new CommonMarkCoreExtension());
$environment->addExtension(new PictureExtension());
```

## Syntax

Markdown:

```
[[[
+ img_1 {media:"(min-width:650px)"}
+ img_2 {media:"(min-width:465px)"}
- img_3
]]]
```

Html:

```html
<picture>
<source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_1" />
<source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_2" />
<img src="img_3" />
</picture>
```

Feel free to contribute: [GitHub](https://github.com/noah1400/commonmark-picture-extension)